# Exchange 2007 account

Tags: password-protection, exchange-server-2007

The employee forgot to put out of office reply in Outlook before you leave on vacation. Is there a way for an administrator to do it for the user without knowing his password? running Exchange 2007

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault http://serverfault.com/tour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps that you need.

To get started in the shell, go to:

> Start > All Programs > Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 > Exchange Management Shell

This opens a window that looks a lot like a normal command window but, instead of using the old `cmd.exe` in the background, this is the new, rather plain-looking PowerShell.

Run the command from exchange shell:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -[mailbox name] -User [Your admin account] -AccessRights FullAccess.
```

From that point, you have full control of the mailbox and should be able to access it with your credentials.

I hope this helps.  Please, let me know if you're still getting hung up.

P.S. Look this issue here. Maybe it will be useful to you.

http://www.ask.com/answers/533844861/i-forgot-my-password-for-outlook-how-can-i-restore-it?qsrc=14106